# Unable to remove Multiindex from dataframe after pivoting data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do `pivot` of a two categorical Variable (`status_type`) in `python` `pandas` but it is resulting in `multiindex` dataframe. I would like this to be a normal dataframe but couldn't figure out how. Would appreciate any help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": np.arange(0, 8), 
                   "Window": np.random.rand(8), 
                   "status_type" : ["snap","perf","snap","perf","snap","perf","snap","perf"],
                   "status_level": [1, 2, 20, 35, 10, 5, 42, 9],
                  })

test_df
```

Pivot:

```
test_df.pivot(index=['id','Window'],columns='status_type',values='status_level')
```

Result in Multi index df:
[image: result]

I have tried below code to reset it into normal dataframe and remove `status_type` column but it didn't work.

```
(test_df
.pivot(index=['id','Window'], columns='status_type', values='status_level')
.reset_index()
.drop('status_type', axis = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
(test_df.pivot(index=['id','Window'],columns='status_type',values='status_level')
 .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   id    Window  perf  snap
0   0  0.218674   NaN   1.0
1   1  0.744127   2.0   NaN
2   2  0.888882   NaN  20.0
3   3  0.399161  35.0   NaN
4   4  0.955325   NaN  10.0
5   5  0.938839   5.0   NaN
6   6  0.874510   NaN  42.0
7   7  0.964414   9.0   NaN
```

Comment: Yes this looks good and exactly what I needed. Thanks. Will accept it as soon as it let me.

Answer (score 1):

[image: This will help you resolve using reset and iloc ,and previous solution is more efficient as we are doing within the pivot function thanks to Paul]

This will help you resolve using reset and iloc ,and previous solution is more efficient as we are doing within the pivot function thanks to Paul